# How to add missing rows per group in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark

The input dataset looks like this:

```
org| id |step| value
1  |  1 | 1  | 12  
1  |  1 | 2  | 13 
1  |  1 | 3  | 14 
1  |  1 | 4  | 15   
1  |  2 | 1  | 16  
1  |  2 | 2  | 17 
2  |  1 | 1  | 1  
2  |  1 | 2  | 2
```

for the output I want to add the missing `step`s per `org` group for example to `id == 2` of `org == 1`

```
org| id |step| value
1  |  1 | 1  | 12  
1  |  1 | 2  | 13 
1  |  1 | 3  | 14 
1  |  1 | 4  | 15   
1  |  2 | 1  | 16  
1  |  2 | 2  | 17 
1  |  2 | 3  | null 
1  |  2 | 4  | null   
2  |  1 | 1  | 1  
2  |  1 | 2  | 2
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
r = df.select("org", "step").distinct() 
df.join(r, ["org", "step"], 'right_outer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
val l = df.select("org", "step");
val r = df.select("org", "id");
val right = l.join(r, "org");

val result = df.join(right, Seq("org", "id", "step"), "right_outer").distinct().orderBy("org", "id", "step");

result.show
```

Gives:

```
+---+---+----+-----+                                                            
|org| id|step|value|
+---+---+----+-----+
|  1|  1|   1|   12|
|  1|  1|   2|   13|
|  1|  1|   3|   14|
|  1|  1|   4|   15|
|  1|  2|   1|   16|
|  1|  2|   2|   17|
|  1|  2|   3| null|
|  1|  2|   4| null|
|  2|  1|   1|    1|
|  2|  1|   2|    2|
+---+---+----+-----+
```

Bonus: sql query for the table (`orgs`) reflecting the `df` contents

```sql
select distinct o_right."org", o_right."id", o_right."step", o_left."value"
from orgs as o_left
right outer join (
        select o_in_left."org", o_in_right."id", o_in_left."step"
        from orgs as o_in_right
        join (select "org", "step" from orgs) as o_in_left
        on o_in_right."org" = o_in_left."org"
        order by "org", "id", "step"
    ) as o_right
on o_left."org" = o_right."org"
    and o_left."step" = o_right."step"
    and o_left."id" = o_right."id"
order by "org", "id", "step"
```

Comment: Thank it works but having two joins and four distinct it's not really feasible to run It against my data. Is there any way to skip some of the distincts?

Comment: You can skip the first three `distincts`... but it does not improve the performance. I will try to find another approach

Comment: I've edited the answer (removed the unnecessary distincts and the right outer join from the inner select). What is the approximate volume of the data?

Comment: thanks for your time. It's close enough to what I'm looking for